# Object reference not set to an instance of an object - Error

Tags: arrays, vb.net, list, nullreferenceexception

I have an enum which is array list ( its optional you can add items up to 5 times)

```
Public DiseaseTreatment() As TreatmentsetDiseaseTreatment

Public Enum TreatmentsetDiseaseTreatment
'''<remarks/>
<System.Xml.Serialization.XmlEnumAttribute("01")>  _
Item01

''<remarks/>
Antibiotics
''<remarks/>
<System.Xml.Serialization.XmlEnumAttribute("02")>  _
Item02

'''<remarks/>
<System.Xml.Serialization.XmlEnumAttribute("Pain Killers)")>  _
PainKillers
```

*break*

```
Dim temptreatment As List(Of TreatmentsetDiseaseTreatment)= New List(Of TreatmentsetDiseaseTreatment)()
temptreatment.Add("Painkiller")
For i As Integer = 0 To temptreatment(i) - 1
   test.TreatmentTypes(i) = temptreatment(i)
Next
```

When I hover over `tempTreatment(i)` it has the right string `"painkiller"` so I do not understand how is it throwing `NullReferenceException`?

Comment: Enums are not arrays, lists or arraylists.  They are just Enums - groups of constants with names. What is `TreatmentsetDiseaseTreatment` ?

Comment: Sorry I updated the code. That is the Enum name, I've copied the correct line.. I tried loads of stuff and I don't get it at all.. I managed to do all the ones without the () the above DiseaseTreatment() is list. so how shall I deal with it ?

Comment: No, its not duplicate. My one when I hover over it show me data but then I get error?!!

Comment: It is a duplicate and it's probably because `test` is `null` so calling `test.TreatmentTypes(i)` would throw an NRE.

Comment: If you follow the top answer outlined in the marked duplicate you will be able to better trouble shoot what variable is `null`.

Comment: Conceptually, it is a duplicate.  There is only one cause for a NRE, but this seems to be an edge case.  `test` is not initialized anywhere.  I think you are way off base in what you are doing.  If some value can be a combination of treatments, it needs to be a flag.  Why you are doing any of this when you can get the Enum values ot names very easily is a mystery

Comment: Thiis is the line of code I used on my previous values where Enum was not a list -  ([Enum].Parse(GetType(Bloodtype), getData.code) and It worked perfectly however the fact DiseaseTreatment() its causing issues so I am trying to find a way to solve it

Comment: Yea, an Enum is never a list.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You want to stop at the end of the array, not at the end of the x item in the array.

```
For i As Integer = 0 To temptreatment.Count - 1
```

Not

```
For i As Integer = 0 To temptreatment(i) - 1
```

Comment: "length is not a member of type list" I think I am doing something completely wrong. I've never used list and new to vb.net. I will try to read more about lists and how to go about it with Enums. the other enums where straightforward hopefully this one too! Cheers

Comment: @Sam - sorry, that should have been `Count` not `Length`. The latter is the property on an array.

Comment: Yeah, that's right but I still have error. Can you recommend a link to learn about the enums which have list type ( the only different with this one from the previous ones I did with enums, you can have multiple treatments) If you could direct me to a good place to start reading about I will very much appreciate it.

Comment: @Sam - Most of the content out there is for c# but I think its not too complex to easily translate to vb.net. What you are searching for is called [Enum Flags](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.flagsattribute%28v=vs.110%29.aspx). This offers the ability to combine multiple states into a single value. Keyword browser search: [.net enum flags](https://www.google.com/search?q=.net+enum+flags&oq=.net+enum+flags)

Comment: Thanks! but my Enum class, I am not meant to change it and they didnt use flag.. I've looked at it quick but thanks very much for giving me some reading material for this problem I have.